# Solving first order differential equation with three variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Don't even know where to begin on this one.  Solve the system
$$\begin{cases}tx'+y'=1\\y'+x+e^{x'}=1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Just to clarify, are $y$ and $x$ functions of $t$?

Comment: yes, sorry x' = x'(t) and y' = y'(t)

Comment: What's throwing me off the most is the e^(x')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute the first equation into the second one to obtain

$$ -tx'+x+e^{x'}=0.$$

I leave it as an exercise to show that the solution must be of the form

$$ x(t) = C_1t+C_2. $$

Substitute it into the equation above and you get

$$ x(t) = Ct -e^C.$$

Now we can solve $y(t)$:

$$ y(t) = \int 1-tx' dt = \int 1-Ct dt= t-\frac{Ct^2}{2}+D.$$

Comment: I understand the first part, but where I need help is how you obtain x(t) = C1t+C2

Comment: @user372021 There won't be any (easy) solution if e^(x') is not a constant, so x(t) would have to be a first degree polynomial.